# How could scrapy parse this kind of links?they are not all in the html source code

Tags: python, scrapy

The html source like this:

```
<a href='/45179'><span>&laquo;Prev</span></a><span>1</span>
<a href='/45157/2'><span>2</span></a>
<a href='/45157/3'><span>3</span></a>
<a href='/45157/4'><span>4</span></a>
<span class='dots'>…</span>
<a href='/45157/21'><span>21</span></a>
<a href='/45157/2'><span>Next&raquo;</span></a>
```

Piece of my scrapy code like this：

```
rules = [
    Rule(sle(allow=("http://www.domain.com/\d{5}/\d+$", )), callback='parse_2'),
    ]
```

It can only get 4 urls;

```
/45157/2
/45157/3
/45157/4
/45157/21
```

how could I get No5 to No20 page?

Comment: I want get No1~No21，need no5~no20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select always the one URL containing the "Next" text and create a `Request` object and `yield` it from your `parse_2` method.

Alternatively add the `follow=True` to your Rule like in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). In this case it would be done automatically.

Comment: You mean Rule change like this?  Rule(sle(allow=("http://www.domain.com/\d{5}/\d+$", )), follow=True ,callback='parse_2'),

Comment: Yes, that's right. As the documentation states: if you provide the `callback` method the value of `follow` is set to `False`. In your case you need to set it manually to `True` to follow the internal links on the scraped sites too.